# Set Pixels to PictureBox

Tags: c#, graphics, pixel, imaging

Context: I have a program that gets the ArGB of any image. Throws it into a `Color ARGBFormat = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);` Now I would like to put that into a PictureBox. I do not have a complete Pixel Array (It is more or less scattered).

Code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ImagePath);
Rectangle bmpRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height); //Creates Rectangle for holding picture
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(bmpRec, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); //Gets the Bitmap data
IntPtr Pointer = bmpData.Scan0;
int DataBytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height; //Gets array size
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[DataBytes]; //Creates array
Marshal.Copy(Pointer, rgbValues, 0, DataBytes); //Copies of out memory
StringBuilder EveryPixel = new StringBuilder(" ");
int PixelSize = 4;
Color ARGBFormat;
Bitmap ImageOut = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
        {
            int offSet = x * PixelSize;
            // read pixels
            byte blue = row[offSet];
            byte green = row[offSet + 1];
            byte red = row[offSet + 2];
            byte alpha = row[offSet + 3];
            ARGBFormat = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);
            ImageOut.SetPixel(x, y, ARGBFormat); //Slow
            EveryPixel.Append(ARGBFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use that code that I have been working on ^ to be displayed into a PictureBox without using SetPixels. I want to use LockBits as it is the most optimize method.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

initialization code before the loop

```
BitmapData bitmapData = ImageOut.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

byte[] pixels = new byte[bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 4]; //4 means 1 byte for each a r g b
IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
Marshal.Copy(ptr , pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
```

update the pixels within the loop

```
pixels[offSet] = blue;
pixels[offSet + 1] = green;
pixels[offSet + 2] = red;
pixels[offSet + 3] = alpha;
```

finally to cleanup the code

```
bitmapData.UnlockBits();
```

so for me code look like

```
unsafe
{

   BitmapData bitmapData = ImageOut.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

   byte[] pixels = new byte[bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 4]; //4 means 1 byte for each a r g b
   IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
   Marshal.Copy(ptr , pixels, 0, pixels.Length);

   for (int y = 0; y < bmpData.Height; y++)
   {
        byte* row = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0 + (y * bmpData.Stride);
        for (int x = 0; x < bmpData.Width; x++)
        {
            int offSet = x * PixelSize;
            // read pixels
            byte blue = row[offSet];
            byte green = row[offSet + 1];
            byte red = row[offSet + 2];
            byte alpha = row[offSet + 3];

            //copy to target
            pixels[offSet] = blue;
            pixels[offSet + 1] = green;
            pixels[offSet + 2] = red;
            pixels[offSet + 3] = alpha;
        }
    }
    bitmapData.UnlockBits();
}

//set to picturebox
pictureBox.Image = ImageOut;
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest and help but I need to display them into a PictureBox. Do you have anything idea how?

Comment: this is fairly simple `pictureBox.Image = ImageOut;`